# Application Failed to Launch in Time, even with a background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, reachability

I am checking network reachability in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performReachabilityCheck) withObject:nil];
```

Background thread

```
-(void)performReachabilityCheck{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [internetReach startNotifer];
        [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: internetReach];
    [pool release]; pool = nil;
}
```

I'm not sure why my app fails to launch in time?

Comment: A different way of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk/3597085#3597085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: internetReach];` correctly updating the UI in the main thread?  If not, that could be a problem.

Otherwise, I would suggest you make sure that your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is correctly returning quickly as you expect.

Another thing to try is to break into the debugger as the app is firing up but before it has failed to launch.  Check the backtrace and make sure the main event loop is in a sensible state (as it sounds like it isn't).