# WP7 Reachability

Tags: networking, windows-phone-7, reachability

If you look at the iPhone, there are many examples on how to perform reachability network checks as well as best practices:

I've found the following existing questions on SO:

[Where should I perform a Reachability check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953717/where-should-i-perform-a-reachability-check)

[Reachability Guide for iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790957/reachability-guide-for-ios-4)

[iPhone reachability checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking)

Apple developers, in addition, have an example of how to use their Reachability class:
[Apple Code Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

I haven't seen resources like this for WP7 yet.  The AppHub's [example code](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/wp7_code_samples) shows projects that communicate to the web, but none (at least that I saw) that perform reachability checks.  In addition, though [Charles Pretzold's free 1000 page PDF](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) has many excellent examples and explanations, none of them concern reachability.

Has anyone done this yet or found solid examples?

<strike>**UPDATE:** Has [NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterfaceType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.networkinformation.networkinterface.getinternetinterfacetype(VS.92).aspx) been proven to work on devices?</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to know which network connection is currently active, you can do this.

[NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterfaceType Method (Microsoft.Devices.NetworkInformation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.networkinformation.networkinterface.getinternetinterfacetype%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Not sure if that will give you what you're after though. I understand you specifically asked for reachability via a chosen network connection, but figured the result you might be after in the end is to work out which network connection is active.. have a look anyway and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mick.  I actually just found this after more searching.  Do you know if this works on devices?

Comment: Sure does, here's the results on emu/device - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/eb521302-2b9d-40c2-8e7c-4f18d548ab67

Comment: ps - for people referencing this, please be aware of and prepared to deal with possible performance of this api - follow the outcome here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/66651.aspx. An alternative means of tracking network connectivity status would be to track the related events.